# Using floating IP for load-balanding OpenShift/OKD control plane

Tags: failover, keepalived, openshift-origin

On-prem OpenShift installation requires load-balancer over the control plane, and does so already for installation. Now this cluster will be local, with the control plane only accessible inside intranet, so setting up additional proxy would:

- Add an element that has to be maintained.
- Either creates a single point of failure, or requires setting up one more system managing redundancy.
- Add latency for absolutely no gain.

But there exists a way to add the required fail-over without any additional elements: floating IP address.

There is the [keepalived](https://keepalived.org/), which can manage floating IP fairly easily, and there are even reasonably looking containers with it, e.g. [osixia/keepalived](https://hub.docker.com/r/osixia/keepalived), and one that should be even able to read the configuration from Kubernetes itself though I didn't yet understand how it works, [osixia/keepalived-confd](https://hub.docker.com/r/osixia/keepalived-confd).

But how do I get it—or anything else suitable—installed into the FCOS nodes, including the bootstrap one, as they try to start?